# PCIe UIO multi-DWORD access issues

Tags: fpga, pci-e

I have an Intel FPGA PCIe endpoint. It shows up correctly in `lspci` and all of the `lspci -vv` information looks correct (memory map, IRQ, BAR0 size all look OK). I want to stream some data over BAR0 and read/write status registers inside of my IP. My host machine has an Intel x86_64 CPU and running a Debian OS.

What I"m currently doing is this:

1. `open()` call to `/sys/class/uio/uio0/device/resource0` -> returns a file descriptor.
2. `mmap` 4 KB on that file descriptor with PROT_READ + PROT_WRITE protection, and MAP_SHARED flags. Offset is 0. --> returns a pointer.
3. In a loop, set offsets relative to the pointer to random numbers. Do this for ~1000 bytes, 4 bytes at a time. After each write to the pointer, call `msync`.
4. Read back the pointer one DWORD at a time.
5. Read back the pointer in bulk using `memcpy`.

The outcome of step #4 is that most of the data looks correct, but some is not (which is strange). The outcome of number 5 is that I get `0xffff_ffff` for everything, which is even stranger.

If I try to replace step #3 with a single `memset / msync` sequence, the program hangs for a little while and then returns a bus error. After this, `lspci` states that BAR0 is disabled and I can no longer interact with it.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? It could be a HW issue, but the HW is really simple right now. I configured the FPGA to act purely as a slave device, with its read response being the registered write data coming across the BAR0 interface. The IP I am working with only has a read-response-valid line (no write response valid, somehow) which I have hard-coded to 1. Seems that burst sizes more than 1 cause some kinds of issues with the PCIe core as seen in the memcpy/memset issues, but I don't see why that would be the case.

EDIT/UPDATE:

I was able to work around this. Supposedly the MMIO is only for 32b, so writing a loop that access the pointer 32b at a time is the solution here.

Comment: Do you know if mmap maps the address space as non-cacheable?

Comment: A guess regarding step 5: it may be that memcpy is using an operation size that isn't supported by the MMIO interface of the device. For example MMIO may support only 4-byte accesses and memcpy may be using 1-byte or 8-byte or even 64-byte accesses, depending on which version of memcpy you're using and what optimizations it has implemented.

Comment: Hi prl, how do I check if the address space is non-cacheable, and what the MMIO operation size supported is? I am using Intel's own PCIe hard-ip, so anything that happens inside of it w.r.t. the actual protocol is a black box to me. My interface to that IP is just handshake signals.

Comment: Do the handshake signals coming to you from the PCIe IP include a DWORD count and byte-enables? (I would assume they must.) From that you can detect what type of accesses are arriving and check if you handle all the various sizes. (I also assume that the PCIe IP itself can correctly process and pass through any accesses allowed by PCIe, or at least any that the Intel processor can generate.)

Comment: Is your FPGA able to respond to read requests at the full rate that they could come in through the PCIe IP? If not, have you implemented flow control to prevent accesses from arriving faster than you can handle them? (Again, I don't know anything about the PCIe IP, but I assume it must support that.)

Comment: No DWORD count, but there are byte-enables. I haven't done anything with them.

Comment: AFAIK, the PCIe IP is really supposed to handle all of the real protocol stuff. The interface that's exposed to the user is just the Avalon or AXI bus interface. In my super simple design, I am just hard-coding both the read response status and data, so no flow control should be necessary.

Comment: I’m confused. If you’re hard-coding the read data, how is it that you expect to be able to return the data written?

Comment: I was storing the write data before; now I am just hard-coding the read response data for a sanity check. Currently my greater concern is that memset/msync seem to cause the device to be unreachable by the host, which is a greater concern to me.